# How do I paste into a row based on the value of a column

Tags: excel, vba

It may be already on here and Ive missed it but I'm having trouble working out how to change my code from pasting into the last row to pasting into a specific row.

Each dataset has a unique number in column A.
I need to paste the Array into the row which matches the unique reference on the data entry Sheet.

So if the data entry sheet (Enter Action), has "123" in cell C3, I need it to look at the database (RAW DATA) and find the row with "123" in Column A and paste the Array into this row.

I have only ever pasted into the last row before and don't know how to change the below code to do what I need.

```
Dim vCopy, i As Long, rPaste As Range
vCopy = Array("C3", "C5", "Q26", "C7", "C9", "Q26", "C11", "C13", "C15", "G13", "G3", "C17", "G7", "G9", "K3", "G11", "K9")

Set rPaste = Sheets("RAW DATA").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)

For i = LBound(vCopy) To UBound(vCopy)
  rPaste.Value = Sheets("Enter Action").Range(vCopy(i)).Value
  Set rPaste = rPaste.Offset(, 1)
 Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Find`:

```
Dim vCopy, i As Long, f As Range, lookFor

vCopy = Array("C3", "C5", "Q26", "C7", "C9", "Q26", "C11", "C13", "C15", _
              "G13", "G3", "C17", "G7", "G9", "K3", "G11", "K9")

lookFor = Sheets("Enter Action").range("c3").value
Set f = Sheets("RAW DATA").Columns(1).find(lookFor, lookat:=xlWhole)

If not f is nothing then
    For i = LBound(vCopy) To UBound(vCopy)
        f.Offset(0, i).Value = Sheets("Enter Action").Range(vCopy(i)).Value 'fixed#2
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. When I run it it comes up with a 'Run-time error '424': Object required'. Have I missed something?

Comment: I had a typo on the 'fixed' line.  should be fine now

Comment: Now I have run time error 1004 application defined or object efined error :(  The excel gods are not looking down on me tonight lol!

Comment: If you have an error it's always useful to mention which line it's occurring on./

Comment: Its not telling me- just coming up with the pop up box. It seems to alternate between 400 and 1004.

Comment: No "debug" button?

Comment: Just tried- If I use F8 to step through, it comes up with 1004after 'f.offset.... line

Comment: Sorry not my day and i should give up posting without testing.  Scrap the `-1` in that line since the lbound of the array is already zero...

Comment: still no luck :( I'm going to give up for today and sleep on it.  Thank-you so much for all your help today!!!

Comment: Maybe its something elsewhere messing it up then- Ill recheck everything. Thanks for all your help